# What is a R6010 error?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, visual-c++

I ran into a problem whereby my executable may receive an abort/retry/ignore dialog such as:

Debug Error!
Program: ...whatever.exe

R6010
- abort() has been called

I believe it is because I have an unhandled exception and I can replicate the problem with this simple program:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    catch (std::logic_error& e)
    {

    }

    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Is my assumption correct (it is caused by an unhandled exception)?  I have found plenty of examples online for the error but nothing that actually defines what the error code means.

This error only occurs in my debug build.  My release build will just hang before crashing out (which is what I expect for the unhandled exception).

Comment: This happens if there's an assertion: `assert( condition )` - which are only checked/compiled in the debug build. Unhandled exceptions make assertions internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens if there's an assertion: `assert( condition );`.

Assertions are only checked/compiled in the debug build.

Unhandled exceptions make assertions internally, in order to allow the developer to interrupt and debug the program and to find the error.

In release build, the application crashes immediately.

If you remove or catch the exception, the error will not appear anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I looked into ``std::terminate`` and ``std::abort`` which led me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx. This pretty much explains everything I need to know. In my code I have an ``Exception`` class that acts as a base class to other exceptions. However, an instance of ``Exception`` was thrown which bubbled up to main.

Comment: In release builds, asserts are not present. The code will continue which may or may not lead to a crash. In release builds, unhandled exceptions will call abort().

Comment: @KlaasvanGend If you are debugging with Visual-Studio and use a standard release-configuration, there will be special kinds of asserts, so that the debugger can pause the application and give control to the developer. But if you are building a standard release candidate, you are right - no assertions there.